# Example of a quasi-isomorphism in $\operatorname{Top}$ which is not a homotopy equivalence

Tags: algebraic-topology

Can we have a continous map $f: X \longrightarrow Y$ such that $f$ induces an isomorphism on all homology groups i.e. $f_* : H_n(X) \longrightarrow H_n(Y)$ is an isomorphism of abelian groups for all $n \geq 0$ but $f$ itself is not a homotopy equivalence?

Comment: Related: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitehead_theorem

Comment: @Neal I think that more than Whitehead's theorem is the fact that if a map $f:X\to Y$ induces an isomorphism on all homology groups, and $X$ and $Y$ are simply connected CW complexes, then $f$ is actually a homotopy equivalence. This is in Chapter Three of Hatcher somewhere.

Answer (score 3):

Yes; in fact, it is possible for a noncontractible space (even a CW complex) to have the same homology as a point; such spaces are called *acyclic*. An example of such a thing can be obtained by removing a point from a homology sphere.

However, <s>if $f$ is also required to be an isomorphism on $\pi_1$ and the spaces are connected, then $f$ is a weak homotopy equivalence</s>. This follows from the relative Hurewicz theorem and the fact that $\pi_1(Y,X) = 0$ (assuming $f$ is an inclusion). If the spaces are CW complexes, then it follows from the Whitehead theorem that $f$ is in fact a homotopy equivalence.

---

edit: This last statement wasn't quite true. It's true if $X$ and $Y$ are simply connected, or if certain weaker conditions hold (see the comments below).

Comment: The relative Hurewicz theorem only gives you that $\pi_1(X)$ acts transitively on the relative homotopy groups, not their vanishing. You have to pass to the homology of the universal covers: A map between connected $CW$-complexes is a homotopy equivalence if and only if it is a $\pi_1$-iso and induces an isomorphism on homology of the universal covers of the spaces in question.

Comment: As a reference for Fabian's comment, see Hatcher 4.35 and 4.74.

Comment: Ah, I misremembered how it went, then. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The [Warsaw circle](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Warsaw+circle) has all its homology groups trivial, except $H_0$.  There is a map from $S^0$ to the circle that induces isomorphisms on all homology groups.  But, they are not homotopy equivalent.